# Как убрать неравенства при повороте layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Код разметки `activity`  :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutFrameFirst"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/frame_left_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/frame_top_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/frame_right_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/frame_bottom_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_margin="-1dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
lLFrameFirst = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutFrameFirst);
lLFrameFirst.setRotation(FRAME_ROTATION_LEFT);
```

Задаю  поворот в  20 градусов, при повороте  отображает с неровностями по краям `ImageView` и `LinearLayout` как их убрать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо включить antialiasing для изображения

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).setAntiAlias(true);
```