# Повернуть элемент View

Tags: android, xml, view

Я хочу повернуть элемент `View` , `linearLayoutFrameFirst` на 20 градусов, как мне это сделать?

Вот код разметки :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:src="@drawable/background">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutFrameFirst"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/frame_left_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/frame_top_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/frame_right_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/frame_bottom_margin">

<ImageView
android:layout_width="82dp"
android:layout_height="82dp"
android:id="@+id/imageView2"
android:padding="1dp"
android:background="#ff000000"
android:layout_margin="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если приложение API11+, то поможет
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)

Comment: Спасибо, повернуло, но появились неровности по краям layout,  как их можно убрать?

Comment: Ответил здесь
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431390/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-layout